# Minecraft: Does anyone know of a working config for ftb utilities specificly the badges

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have been trying to get badges to work on my server for a few days now and haven't had any luck. 
Here is the part I am talking about in the config.

```
"login": {
    "customBadges": "https://path.to.img.png",
    "motd": [
        "Welcome to the server!"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for assistance about modded Minecraft

Comment: @Kappei Each and every question within [minecraft-feed-the-beast] tag is asking for assistance with modded Minecraft. Do you propose to close all questions with this tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1**: Make a file in pastebin.com, following this example: http://pastebin.com/Mu8McdDR

**Step 2**: Click on Raw and copy-paste that link in server's local/config/ftbu.json's "badges" value.

**Step 3**: Re-login or restart server and it should be done.

**Source**: Private message from **LatvianModder** on reddit.